# How to modify variables from twisted Protocol methodes such as ConnectionMade

Tags: python, protocols, twisted, factory, reactor

I'm new to python and much more to Twisted, so sorry if the title is not clear enough, but I'll do my best to describe my problem.

I want to separate the logic and networking parts in my application, so I have 2 classes Controller and SimpleServer, I have a variable named nodes in Controller which I want to update by adding the Client Ip of each connection, It's probably obvious for python experts, but I can't get it. Please, take a look at my code. I commented the line where I'm stuck.

Thanks for any help

**controller.py**

```
class Controller(object):
    nodes = []
    def __init__(self, port):
        ss= SimpleServer(port)
```

**server.py**

```
class MyServerProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self): 
        #ctrl.nodeList.append(self.transport.getPeer()) #this is what I want to do

class ControllerFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MyServerProtocol()

class SimpleServer():
    def __init__(self, port):
        reactor.listenTCP(port, ControllerFactory()) #@UndefinedVariable
        print 'server listening on %d' %port
        reactor.run() #@UndefinedVariable
```

**Main Program**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 9123
    ctrl = Controller(port)
```

**Client Side**

```
class myClientProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print ("data received", data)

class myClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected.'
        return myClientProtocol()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "CLIENT : connecting to : [ %s ] on [ %s ]\n" %(IP,PORT)
    reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1',9123, myClientFactory()) #@UndefinedVariable
    reactor.run() #@UndefinedVariable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need references to the right objects.

Just like you needed a reference to the reactor so you imported `twisted.internet.reactor` so you could call the run method.

**controller.py**

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, port):
        # Don't set self.nodes as a class attribute or it is shared across all instances
        self.nodes = [] 
        # Don't just use a local for SimpleServer, keep a reference on an attribute.  Also, pass the controller instance in.
        self.ss = SimpleServer(port, self)
```

**server.py**

```
class MyServerProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self): 
        # Get the reference to the Controller instance.
        ctrl = self.factory.server.controller
        # Use it.
        ctrl.nodeList.append(self.transport.getPeer())    

class ControllerFactory(Factory):
    # Set this class attribute so the inherited buildProtocol does the work for us, including setting the factory attribute.
    protocol = MyServerProtocol
    def __init__(self, server):
        # Save a reference to the given server as an attribute on the instance.
        self.server = server
        Factory.__init__(self)

class SimpleServer():
    def __init__(self, port, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        # Pass a reference to the SimpleServer instance to the ControllerFactory
        reactor.listenTCP(port, ControllerFactory(self))
        print 'server listening on %d' %port
        reactor.run()
```

**Main Program**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 9123
    ctrl = Controller(port)
```

**Client Side**

```
class myClientProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print ("data received", data)

class myClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected.'
        return myClientProtocol()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "CLIENT : connecting to : [ %s ] on [ %s ]\n" %(IP,PORT)
    reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1',9123, myClientFactory()) #@UndefinedVariable
    reactor.run() #@UndefinedVariable
```

I've made the smallest set of changes I can see to demonstrate the solution.  I haven't tested the resulting code.  Hopefully, you can see that what I've done is take references to the objects that one part of your code has and pass them to other parts of your code that needs them.  This frequently takes the form of passing arguments to functions (initializer, methods, whatever) and setting attributes on objects (generally whatever self refers to).

I haven't tried to improve the maintainability of the code or correct any fraught patterns.  This code is still not a model of ideal software but it should at least let you append a value to the list you want it appended to.

Some other suggestions I would make are:

- Use more descriptive names
- Use less indirection
- Don't make `__init__` have side-effects other than setting attributes on `self`
- Don't violate the law of Demeter *so* hard
- Don't do whatever you're doing (probably a `*` import?) that caused you to sprinkle `#@UndefinedVariable` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the prompt answer, and the precious advice too, as I told in my post, I am new to python but ready to improve myself.

I've analyzed your changes, I'm starting to understand the principle, but there's one thing I didn't understand: the call to Factory. **_init**(self), moreover this line generates an error, I changed them to ControllerFactory.**init**(self), and finally  I delete it. I added some missed initializations and it works, a thousand thanks :)

Here is the final code that works the way I want it to work.

**controller.py**

```
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, port):
    # Don't set self.nodes as a class attribute or it is shared across all instances
    self.port = port
    self.nodes = [] 

    # Don't just use a local for SimpleServer, keep a reference on an attribute.  Also, pass the controller instance in.
    self.ss = SimpleServer(port, self)
```

**server.py**

```
class MyServerProtocol(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self): 
        # Get the reference to the Controller instance.
        ctrl = self.factory.server.controller
        # Use it.
        ctrl.nodes.append(self.transport.getPeer())    

class ControllerFactory(Factory):
    # Set this class attribute so the inherited buildProtocol does the work for us, including setting the factory attribute.
    protocol = MyServerProtocol
    def __init__(self, server):
        # Save a reference to the given server as an attribute on the instance.
        self.server = server
        #ControllerFactory.__init__(self)

class SimpleServer():
    def __init__(self, port, controller):
        self.port = port
        self.controller = controller
        # Pass a reference to the SimpleServer instance to the ControllerFactory
        reactor.listenTCP(self.port, ControllerFactory(self))
        print 'server listening on %d' %port
        reactor.run()
```

**Main Program**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = 9123
    ctrl = Controller(port)
```

**Client Side**

```
class myClientProtocol(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print ("data received", data)

class myClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print 'Connected.'
        return myClientProtocol()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "CLIENT : connecting to : [ 127.0.0.1 ] on [ 9123 ]\n" 
    reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1',9123, myClientFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

- I'll try now to consider your last remarks.